# Script to execute command line function like rsync or mv that depends on user input

Tags: python, command-line, subprocess, rsync, pysimplegui

I like the `rsync` command but wanted to put a GUI on it to help me learn python. Everything works except I have no idea how to get the `rsync` command and the user-provided input to the command line.

OSX 10.15.7  Sublime (Build 4107)

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import os
from pathlib import Path
import subprocess


layout = [[sg.Text('Sync Your Files')],
          [sg.Text('Source Folder', size=(15, 1))],
          [sg.FolderBrowse(key='source'), sg.InputText(key='-source-')],
          [sg.Text('Target Folder', size=(15, 1))],
          [sg.FolderBrowse(key='target'), sg.InputText(key='-target-')],
          [sg.Button('Submit'), sg.Button('Cancel')]],


window = sg.Window('Simple Data Entry Window', layout)
event, values = window.read(close=True)


print(values['-source-'])
print(values['-target-'])

begining = (values['-source-'])
end = (values['-target-'])

syncommand = ("rsync -avzh ")
args=[syncommand + begining + end]
print(args)


if event == 'Submit':
    os.system('args')
    execute(args)
    print('Your files from ', values['-source-'], 'were copied to your ',
          values['-target-'])
else:
    print('User cancelled')
```

Comment: Use [`subprocess.run()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run) and pass the arguments to it as a list of strings — there, now you have an idea of how to do it.

Comment: Have you looked at the "Exec APIs" that are part of PySimpleGUI? The Cookbook and Call Reference both have information on them.  There are a number of demo programs that show their use too.

Answer (score -1):

Change to:

```
args=[syncommand , begining+'/*' , end]
print(args)


if event == 'Submit':
  os.system(' '.join(args))
```

And remove the "execute()". **First** to store in a list u need to put ',' not '+' because with '+' the result is "beginning/path/end/path" not "beginning/path/" "end/path/". **Second** need to add '/*' to beginning otherwise will copy the file not the content of the file. **Third** add ' '.join he transform the list to a string to `os.system` works properly.

Comment: Worked like a charm!  Thank you for your help James Bond'Cama and everyone else too.